# Undefined variable: is_tree when using Wordpress.org Code Snippet

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, undefined

While typing this I'm being told there are many similarly phrased questions with answers to this in Stackoverflow - but having read many of the other queries I'm still no nearer to solving the issue I seem to be having regarding an error message about an undefined variable.

To explain . . .

I'm using a code snippet in my child theme functions file to test for sub-Pages which I've taken from the following Wordpress.org reference page:
(snippet 4 in https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/).

I've added 2 lines below the code to A) define what `$pid` is and B) an if statement that defines which sub pages I want to call up (see last 2 lines in the code below):

```
 * Check whether we are on this page or a sub page
 *
 * @param int $pid Page ID to check against.
 * @return bool True if we are on this page or a sub page of this page.
 */
function wpdocs_is_tree( $pid ) {      // $pid = The ID of the page we're looking for pages underneath
    $post = get_post();               // load details about this page
 
    $is_tree = false;
    if ( is_page( $pid ) ) {
        $is_tree = true;            // we're at the page or at a sub page
    }
 
    $anc = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );
    foreach ( $anc as $ancestor ) {
        if ( is_page() && $ancestor == $pid ) {
            $is_tree = true;
        }
    }
    return $is_tree;  // we arn't at the page, and the page is not an ancestor
}
?>

<?php $pid = is_page(array('my-newcomen','the-piston-engine-revolution')) ?>
<?php if (is_page($is_tree) && !is_paged() && !is_page('society-business','journal-archive')) {?>
```

The code has worked OK for a while but the website is now becoming very slow. Having installed the 'Query Monitor' plugin I can see various php errors that I want to clear up/debug - and this is one of them.

The error message says that the variable $is_tree on line 579 (which is the last line in the above code `<?php if (is_page($is_tree) && !is_paged() && !is_page('society-business','journal-archive')) {?>`) is undefined.

This area of php is beyond my current understanding - but for me the `$is_tree` variable **is defined** as either `$is_tree = false;` or `$is_tree = true;` . . . but obviously this is not the case!

I'd very much appreciate if someone could look at the above code and let me know

A) why the variable is being seen as undefined
and
B) how I go about successfully defining it in order to resolve the error message

Many thanks

Phil

Comment: `$is_tree` is not defined because that variable is not in the GLOBAL scope. That variable only exists within that function. You can try this `is_page( wpdocs_is_tree( $pid ) )`  as that function will return TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: Been reading up about a variable's scope so now understand that because `$is_tree` is inside the function, it'll be undefined when used outside of it. However still don't get why it's undefined tbh - is it because it's boolean (true/false) - how do you define that? Meanwhile tried your suggestion of using `is_page( wpdocs_is_tree( $pid ) )` in the line `<?php if (is_page($is_tree) && !is_paged() && !is_page('society-business','journal-archive')) {?> ` but it's still saying `is_tree` is undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: How did you use it? Post the exact line you tried. `$is_tree` gets defined when you pass the `$pid` and any of the `if` statements are met.

Comment: I used this as the last line in the code I posted in my original question ```<?php if (is_page( wpdocs_is_tree( $pid ) ) && !is_paged() && !is_page('society-business','journal-archive')) {?> ``` Is that not what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

So, there are a couple things here (based on the last comment):

1. `is_page()` doesn't accept a `bool` value, it needs an id or a page name string (or an array of either.
2. `$is_tree` gets defined when you pass in the `pid` of a page. The function returns `true` or `false`. `$is_tree` isn't used outside of that function - it's simply a holder for the bool value.
3. `wpdocs_is_tree()` takes a single post id as a parameter, but you are passing an array.
4. You are assigning `$pid` to `is_page()` which returns a true or false, not a post id, which is what `wpdocs_is_tree()` is expecting.
5. I also updated the `wpdocs_is_tree()` to use `global $post` on the first line instead of `$post = get_post()` since there's already a global variable available.

Here's what the code should be:

```
/* Check whether we are on this page or a sub page
*
* @param int $pid Page ID to check against.
* @return bool True if we are on this page or a sub page of this page.
*/
function wpdocs_is_tree( $pid ) {      // $pid = The ID of the page we're looking for pages underneath
    global $post;               // load details about this page

    $is_tree = FALSE;

    if ( is_page( $pid ) ) {
        $is_tree = TRUE;            // we're at the page or at a sub page
    }

    $anc = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );
    foreach ( $anc as $ancestor ) {
        if ( is_page() && $ancestor === $pid ) {
            $is_tree = TRUE;
        }
    }

    return $is_tree;  // we aren't at the page, and the page is not an ancestor
}

?>

<?php
/* In plain english (in order): if the current page is my-newcomen or the-piston-engine-revolution 
 * AND wpdocs_is_tree returns true by passing the current page id, then continue 
 * AND is NOT society-business or journal-archive
 */
if ( is_page( ['my-newcomen', 'the-piston-engine-revolution'] ) && wpdocs_is_tree( get_queried_object_id() ) && ! is_page('society-business','journal-archive') ) { ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the individual explanations at the beginning of your last comment - nice one - I'm learning all the time. However, when I inserted your code it still didn't work right! Trying to work out what the error is? Basically the the original code is saying . . . If the page is my-newcomen or the-piston-engine-revolution - or a sub-page/child of them. BUT ALSO NOT society-business - or - journal-archive - then proceed. Is that what your last line is saying? (as I can't see any reference to `&& !is_page('society-business','journal-archive')`) - Any ideas as to why it's not yet working?

Comment: There is no reason to check if it's not those two other pages, since the first `is_page( [my-newcom.....` will return `true` if it is or `false` if it's not. Are those other pages children of `my-newcomen` and `the-piston...`? If so, then we would need those checks. Also, now that I see what you are actually trying to do, I'll modify the answer - since it won't catch sub-pages.

Comment: Yes, society-business & journal-archive are both children of my-newcomen hence why that condition is listed (sorry should have been clearer before), How would you modify the answer?

Comment: I've updated the answer. So, basically, the `if` statement will continue if all of those statements are TRUE - is page `my-newcomen` or `the-piston...` AND wpdocs_is_tree returns TRUE AND it's not either of those other pages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but still no joy! Basically where we stand at this point in time is . . . ```if ( is_page( ['my-newcomen', 'the-piston-engine-revolution'] ) && wpdocs_is_tree( get_queried_object_id() ) && ! is_page('society-business','journal-archive') ) { ?>``` doesn't work - while ```<?php $pid = is_page(array('my-newcomen','the-piston-engine-revolution')) ?>
<?php if (is_page($is_tree) && !is_paged() && !is_page('society-business','journal-archive')) {?> ``` Does work - but produces the warning that `$is_tree` is undefined. Any ideas why & how I can resolve this?

Comment: I'm surprised that what you say works if `$is_tree` is undefined since the `if` statement will fail and never be true. I'll see if I can test this locally with a fake site.

Comment: Would it help if I sent you my entire functions file (maybe there's something in there that's causing this behaviour)? Is there a way to attach files to these comments?

Comment: There's not a way to attach the whole file. Is this all in your functions.php? What is in the `if` statement? What are you trying to do - since there may be a better way to accomplish it.

Comment: Yes, it's all in the website's functions file - Can't you put these things up on GitHub? (never used it but could start now?) - I have an ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) group that allows various lists of things to be inputed and displayed on various membership pages (hence the children of |'My Newcomen') but a few of those pages have different field groups to display (hence the `!is_page ('society business', journal-archive')`. Let me know I should sign up to GitHub? Thx btw

Comment: Yeah, you can totally put it up on github.

Comment: Have added to GitHub here: https://github.com/philfutureproof/newcomen_functions - a bit nervous as have made public so you can see it. Didn't know how else to share with you (is that dangerous?). Also not sure if you wanted to ACF fields that relate to this part of the code (or anything else) - let me know - this section starts at line 553

Comment: Was wondering if you had a chance to check out the functions file I put up on GitHub to see why this is not working properly? Your help is much appreciated